# How do I fix this error: [1045] SQLSTATE[28000] [1045]

Tags: mysql, database, localhost

I am working on a server that is not my localhost for the first time. I am renting hosting space from hostgator.  I created a form that is supposed to take the user's information and put it in the database.  I keep on recieving the following error message when I try to submit the form:

> Failed to open database [1045] SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied
>   for user 'username@localhost'@'gator7899.hostgator.com' (using
>   password: YES)

I have seen other posts in which people ask the same question but none of the answers given are working for me.  Also, username is not my actual username and gator7899 is not the actual server.  For security purposes I did not post them here.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure privledges are assigned in your CPanel -> mysql admin -> add user to database
then

you need to change your config to be

```
localhost
username = username of CPanel
password = password of Cpanel
```

Comment: I can't find the configuration file in the control panel or in the file directory.  Any idea on where it would be?  Thank you.

Comment: I would look at the page that is displaying the error, look at the code/line where there is a connection to mysql and append the username and password accordingly.